# Oracle datafiles on a Network Share

Tags: oracle, networking, virtualization, virtual-machine, share

I have an Oracle 8.1.7 Server running on Windows 2000 Advanced Server in a Virtual Machine.  We are currently using MS Virtual Server to host this.  (The allocated hardware is powerful enough - we have 3.5GB RAM assigned, and a single 2GHz processor core, more than most servers in 1999)

One of the limitations of Virtual Server i sthe maximum size of Virtual Hard Disk (127GB) and the database I'm trying to import is 143GB.

To get round this problem, I'm trying to create the DB Datafiles on the physical HDD, which has sufficient space.

My problem is that I'm having difficulty creating a database instance on a network share.

Does anyone know how I can do this while retaining my youthful good looks (and hair!)?

Cheers,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the account your `Oracle` service is started under to have access to the network share.

Can't say it's a good idea to create an `Oracle` datafile on a network share, but it's a viable solution if you don't mess much with you datafiles and share accessibility.

Comment: The plan is to create the DB instance, clear down the tables with huge amounts of data and migrate the smaller, cleaner, greener instance to the host disk.

It's a short term solution...

Comment: I think it will be OK for a one time solution. Run Oracle under an account that has access to the share (default LOCALSYSTEM account doesn't)

Comment: Quassnoi, this is certainly the key point to setting up the data files, however my import still failed.
On further investigation (with attempts and failures) I have come t the conclusion that there is an issue with the dump file.

Answer (score 0):

You say 'import'. If you are using exp/imp, one option may be to only import individual users or tables, and slim them down individually.

Also, the size of an IMP file doesn't correlate to the size of the database. A 140GB exp/imp file may result in a much smaller database (or conversely, it could be larger as the exp/imp file only has the index metadata). Even a database with datafiles totalling 140GB could be smaller if those datafiles contain a lot of unused space.

Comment: Hi Gary,

We're using an EXP file to try and build this.  The EXP file is 75GB, but we've been told the expanded DB size is 140GB.